# JQuery: Filter listelements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists, filtering

I have an unordered list of elements and want to filter out (toggle) all elements with class "alt", but not those which have a second class "links".

### HTML:

```
Toggle: 
<a href="#" id="linkToggle">Links</a>
<a href="#" id="altToggle">ALT</a>

<ul id="errorList" class="nav nav-list" style="height: 190px; overflow: auto;">
    <li class="alt">Alt 1</li>
    <li class="alt">Alt 2</li>
    <li class="alt links">Alt / Links 1</li>
    <li class="alt links">Alt / Links 2</li>
    <li class="links">Links 1</li>
    <li class="links">Links 2</li>
</ul>
```

### jQuery:

```
function toggleClass(cssClass) {
    $("."+cssClass).toggle();
    $("#"+cssClass+'Count').parent().toggleClass("muted");
}


$("#linkToggle").click(function() { 
    $(".links").toggle();  
    $(this).toggleClass("muted");
})
$("#altToggle").click(function() { 
    $(".alt").toggle();    
    $(this).toggleClass("muted");
})
```

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7MnXd/) for you: http://jsfiddle.net/7MnXd/

There you have 6 elements:

- 2 have a class called "links"
- another 2 have a class called "alt"
- and there are to element which has both classes

### What I am tring to archieve:

When clicking on "Link" only "Link 1" & "Link 2" should be filtered out, because "Alt / Links n" have both classes. Both elements should only be filtered out if both toggles are activated. I also tried the [filter() function][2] which jQuery offers, but can't solve the problem. I think I have to check if it's the only class and if not it won't be filtered out, but how to check if the other class is already toggled?

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but my second link is broken.

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: Which classes??? x & y?

Comment: x = alt, y = links
thought that should be clear, if not: please check my jsfiddle

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, after some tests I came to the following solution which might work in others cases as well:

### HTML

```
Toggle: 
<span class="nav-switches">
    <a href="javascript:toggleClass('links');" data-toggle="">Link (<span id="linksCount">0</span>)</a>
    <a href="javascript:toggleClass('alt');" data-toggle="">Text (<span id="altCount">0</span>)</a>
    <a href="javascript:toggleClass('csv');" data-toggle="">CSV (<span id="csvCount">0</span>)</a>
</span>

<ul id="errorList" class="nav nav-list" style="height: 190px; overflow: auto;">
    <li class="alt">Alt 1</li>
    <li class="alt">Alt 2</li>
    <li class="alt links">Alt / Links 1</li>
    <li class="alt links">Alt / Links 2</li>
    <li class="links">Links 1</li>
    <li class="links">Links 2</li>
    <li class="csv">CSV 1</li>
    <li class="csv">CSV 2</li>
    <li class="csv">CSV 3</li>
</ul>
```

### JavaScript

```
window.toggleClass = function(cssClass) {
    // Wird bereits gefiltert und auf aktivierten Filter geklickt?
    if( $("#"+cssClass+'Count').parent().siblings().hasClass("muted") && !$("#"+cssClass+'Count').parent().hasClass("muted") ) {
        $("ul#errorList li").show();
        $("#"+cssClass+'Count').parent().siblings().removeClass("muted");
    } else {
        $("ul#errorList li").hide();
        $("ul#errorList").find("li."+cssClass).show();

        $("#"+cssClass+'Count').parent().siblings().addClass("muted");
        $("#"+cssClass+'Count').parent().removeClass("muted");
    }
}
```

## [View Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G6CVA/)

I hope you like this solution as I do!

Answer (score 0):

Try that if it fits your needs:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7MnXd/2/)

```
$("#linkToggle").click(function() { 
    $(".links").toggle();  //.not('.alt') ???
    $(this).toggleClass("muted");
})
$("#altToggle").click(function() { 
    $(".alt").not('.links').toggle();    
    $(this).toggleClass("muted");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function toggleClass(cssClass) {
    $("."+cssClass).toggle();
    $("#"+cssClass+'Count').parent().toggleClass("muted");
}


$("#linkToggle").click(function() { 
    $(".links:not(.alt)").toggle();  
    $(this).toggleClass("muted");
})
$("#altToggle").click(function() { 
    $(".alt:not(.links)").toggle();    
    $(this).toggleClass("muted");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're after, this will check if one class and one class only is present.

```
$("#linkToggle").click(function() { 
    $("li[class='links']").toggle();  
    $(this).toggleClass("muted");
});

$("#altToggle").click(function() { 
    $("li[class='alt']").toggle();    
    $(this).toggleClass("muted");
});
```